What does 気が抜けなくなった mean?
I have trouble understanding 気が抜ける from this article about the recent effects of the increase of younger children being enrolled at cram schools:

今年中学に上がった娘と小学4年生の息子を持つ都内在住の40代の会社員女性の長女も、プレッシャーにやられてしまった。小3の秋に入塾し、本人が思いのほか頑張り、最難関を目指すクラスに通うことを勧められた。こうなると塾からのプレッシャーもかかってくる。
「御三家を受けてほしい」
面談でもはっきりとそう言われるようになっていた。成績が良いことは誇らしいものの、5年生の2月から毎週のようにテストが続いた。成績によってはクラスが「落ちる」こともあるため、常に気が抜けなくなった。
しかも、コロナ禍で学校見学に行くこともできない。本人も「受験したい」というものの、「ここに行きたい」という志望校を決めきれずにいた。

It is my understanding that the phrase 気が抜ける has two primary meanings which I will list here (from 三省堂):

①はりつめていた気持ちがなくなる。
「試合が終わって━」
②〔ビール・サイダーなどの〕
炭酸や特有の風味などが抜ける。

This use here of 気が抜けなくなる seems to be related to the first definition but I find it confusing. It seems like some odd form of negation, because if 気が抜ける means something like "strained feelings go away/disappear", it's like they are disappearing and then reappearing in one action.
It feels a little 回りくどい in that sense.
What does 気が抜けなくなる mean in contrast to 気が抜ける?

You are right that 気が抜ける refers to the first definition here. 気が抜ける means after being focused or in a stressed situation, your mind/body relaxes because that situation has ended.
In contrast, 気が抜けなくなる would then mean that she is unable to relax. She is consistently in the state of stress or focus, and does not have the chance to unwind because she feels the pressure to pass that exam.
It doesn't mean she is repeatedly getting stressed and then relaxing. She is unable to destress because of the pressure.
To address the confusion with the negative verb, you could probably replace 気が抜けなくなる with a positive phrase:

[…]常に張り詰めている。


If you are confused about how the word is being conjugated:

気が抜けなくなる ＝ 気が抜ける ＋ ない(negation) ＋ 成{な}る(to become) = become the state where she does not lose her stress/focus/緊張感

Which is just like something like 走らなくなる, which could refer to someone who used to jog in the mornings but does not anymore.

"does not have the chance to unwind" But doesn't なくなる always imply a change in a state? So would this not imply that 気が抜ける had previously occurred (so, she was previously focused or in a stressed situation, and then her mind/body relaxed because that situation had ended), and then the reverse occurred in which she is now again in a stressed situation. To me that is what is implied by your definition and thus I don't feel 張り詰めている would mean the same thing (would not imply previous relaxation). Thus I am not sure why this phrase would be used because it seems like a redundant nuance

Again, the nuance wouldn't be that she used to be "not stressed", but that she used to lose her stress (in the context of a previously stressful situation). Is this correct?

Hey, just edited the answer. It does mean a change of state. She was doing something and now she is not. I just edited the answer to include this, but I could say something like: 彼は毎朝走ります, and then a week later say something like 彼は走らなくなった。to mean he doesn't run anymore. The guy doesn't run and stop repeatedly, its just a change in what his habits are.

@whatyouexpect Yes, that's correct. She used to be able to destress, but now that she has so much pressure, she is unable to destress. You are right that the nuance would not mean that "she was not stressed".

That makes more sense. It just still seems a little odd because it highlights not just that she used to be able to destress but that there were stressors in the first place. I get the logic but I don't find it intuitive. To use a hinative definition of this phrase, the idea of the state of 「緊張する出来事が終わって、ほっとしたときの感覚のアレ」"going away/subsiding", much less "constantly going away (常に)" takes a few second looks for me to get

Yeah, I totally agree. It's weird when there are multiple grammar points combined.

From grammatical perspective, I think it is also possible to take 気が抜ける as a potential form of 気を抜く.The particle が can mark object in potential expression (cf. The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb).
The difference is, that 気が抜ける is unintentional (her mind is unwound) while 気を抜く (she unwind her own mind) and its potential form 気が抜ける (she is able/affords to unwind her own mind) is somewhat intentional.

"気が抜けなくなった" means "unable to relax" or "can't let my guard down." It implies being in a state of tension, often due to a need for constant focus or pressure, meaning you have to stay alert and can't unwind.
